# PHP DOMDocument's getElementsByTagName()

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <job>
        <id>4200021</id>
        <sector>Downtown</sector>
        <title>Clean Windows</title>
    </job>

    <job>
        <id>2100021</id>
        <sector>Downtown</sector>
        <title>Fix Manholes</title>
    </job>
</xml>
```

I'm using PHP's DOMDocument, and I'm trying to get the `<id>` of the job by searching the title.

I use this to get the `<job>` node in question:

```
$job = $jobDoc->getElementsByTagName('Clean Windows')->item(0)->parentNode;
```

However, I have iterate through all the nodes by calling nodeName for each node to get the correct ID, is there another simpler way to find the correct id using DOMDocument? I can't call getElementsByTagName() again on the parentNode, and doing this manually becomes a problem when I have to search once again, within another node to find the  in the node , which is part of the  nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($your_xml);
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);
$id = $x->query("//title[. = 'Clean Windows']/../id/text()")->item(0)->wholeText;
```

Comment: What's the difference between using wholeText and nodeValue?

Comment: `wholeText` is a propery of a `DOMText` which this would return, `nodeValue` that of a `DOMNode` (or `DOMElement`, etc). But you can just as easily use `$x->query("//title[. = 'Clean Windows']/../id")->item(0)->nodeValue` here I think if you prefer it :).